# Is it Possible to Scroll between Scenes in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

If you have a few scenes that are relatable and where one leads into another (an leading back to where it came from), does anyone know some setup techniques for your SpriteKit app to use UIScrollView to pan horizontally between them?

I only ask because I like the idea of the user seeing whats up ahead as they transition to another scene. I thought of extending SKTransition, but I had no idea how to approach that, plus, UIScrollView seems appropriate with aspects like bounciness and deceleration.

Thanks!

Comment: you can only use the SKTransition functionality, otherwise there's no way to draw two scenes except during a sktransition

Comment: From what I understand, once you present a scene with an added transition, the user (or developer) has no control. You just wait until the transition completes. What I'm saying is that user can't be in a position while they are panning between two scenes and stop to peek ahead to the next scene before completing the gesture and moving to the next scene.